# C++ change priority queue to alphabetical order?

Tags: c++, priority-queue, string-comparison

I am trying to create a priority queue of pairs, with book names (strings) and lengths (int).
I'd like the priority queue to have the earliest title at the top.

By default the priority queue is reverse alphabetical, returning me

```
(This Book, 100)
(A Book, 200)
```

when I'd like them to be the other way around.

I understand in the case of ints etc. I would use the specifier `std::greater<int>`, but what should I use in this case please? Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(void){
    pair <string, int> tPair;
    priority_queue <pair <string, int>> pq;
    
    pq.emplace("A Book", 200);
    pq.emplace("This Book", 100);
    
    while(pq.size() != 0){
        tPair = pq.top();
        cout << "(" << tPair.first << ", " << tPair.second << ")\n";
        pq.pop();       
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As shown in the [reference example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue), you may pass a custom comparer for `std::pair<std::string,int>`.

Comment: You can omit the type in the standard comparators: `std::less<>`, `std::greater<>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) has [`operator >`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) that compares first member and then second member, so you can simply pass [`std::greater`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater) as comparator to your queue (note that you need to pass also `Container` as template argument, because `Comparator` is last template argument):

```
using QueueType = std::pair<std::string, int>;
priority_queue <QueueType, std::vector<QueueType>, std::greater<>> pq;
```

[See it online](https://godbolt.org/z/s8zGajq6G)